# In Vue, how can I get a css style selector from a $ref?

Tags: vuejs2

I'm able to use $ref to isolate the correct chuck of html, but I need a css selector for that chuck.  I wish this worked...

`this.$refs.myref.querySelector()`

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
this.$refs.myref[0].$el
```

it equals

```
document.querySelector(’.myref’)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are, in fact, able to use `querySelector` on a ref *if* the ref in question is referring to a DOM element and not to a child Vue component. The fact that `this.$refs.myref.querySelector()` doesn't work for you leads me to believe that `myref` is a component and not an element.

If the ref is a Vue component, you are still able to reference the root DOM element of the component via its `$el` property. So, in your case: `this.$refs.myref.$el.querySelector()`.

---

Here's a simple example snippet illustrating the difference:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component('child', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <span class="inside-child">Inside Child</span>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$refs.child.$el.querySelector('.inside-child'));
    console.log(this.$refs.div.querySelector('.inside-div'))
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child ref="child"></child>
  <div ref="div">
    <span class="inside-div">Inside Div</span>
  </div>
</div>
```